# how to bind a reference to an initializer

Tags: c++

I have been reading book `C++ Primer`, and I got a question:

> 1. When we ask for a reference to an auto-deduced type, top-level consts in the initializer are not ignored.
> 2. As usual, consts are not top-level when we bind a reference to an initializer.

In the first sentence, I can get a example to understand:

```
const int ci = 0;
auto &g = ci;   // g is a reference of const int, bind to ci
```

How can I understand second sentence? How to bind a reference to an initializer?

Comment: If the book says that it plays loose with terminology. You don't bind a reference to an initializer. You bind a referencce to an object. An initializer is a syntactic construct. `= ci` is an initializer.

Comment: @n.m. If like what you said, then these two sentence is a contradiction, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `=` symbol to bind a reference to an initializer (pedantically speaking, an object being used as an initializer). You posted an example:

```
auto &g = ci;
```

The initializer `ci` is bound to the reference `g`.

Comment: so, in auto &g = ci; g is a reference, ci is an initializer, that's the example of saying how to bind a reference to an initializer, right? Then, I think these two sentences is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes. I don't see what the contradiction is?

Comment: First one says can keep top-level consts, but second one says consts are not top-level when we do that.

Comment: @Nibnat it is saying that the top-level const on `ci` becomes a non-top-level const on `g`

Comment: you mean g is not a const reference? but I have tested that g is a const reference.

Comment: `g` is a reference to const. Top-level qualifiers cannot be used on references.